# Add Custom Icon SCAlertView

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to create an SCAlert in my project with a custom icon. I have searched the Github Page and wrote exactly what the The page told me to.

```
let appearance = SCLAlertView.SCLAppearance(
    showCircularIcon: true
)
let alertView = SCLAlertView(appearance: appearance)
let alertViewIcon = UIImage(named: "IconImage") //Replace the IconImage text with the image name
alertView.showInfo("Custom icon", subTitle: "This is a nice alert with a custom icon you choose", circleIconImage: alertViewIcon)
```

And I have also imported the `SCLAlertView`. However, when I do this I get many errors for example:

```
Expected declaration
```

And

```
Cannot use instance member 'appearance' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available
```

Comment: same error when using .showCustom instead of .showInfo ?

Comment: Sadly yes :( it shows the same errors

Comment: Which version of the library you're using? v0.7.0 is latest one. It is working for me with your code.

Comment: Im using the latest one

Comment: try using     pod 'SCLAlertView', '~> 0.7' , your code works for me too.

Comment: Will it be ok if you send me our file so i can compare

Comment: If you are using 0.7 then your codeblock is not the issue, but probably where you have your code or maybe some conflicting declarations.

Comment: Are you using cocoapods for library integration? Then do `pod update SCLAlertView`

Comment: I have placed it in my viewdidload at the end

Comment: Yes i am using cocoapods